# CONIN (Console In) in CP/M and "old characters" in character latch

Tags: keyboards, cp-m, io

CP/M uses CONIN to read a single character from the keyboard, and it will assert CONST to poll the status register for incoming characters. Let's assume the keyboard controller can buffer one character, has a 1-bit status register, and the I/O is done by polling. Reading a character will clear the status register (set it to 0. )

I assume CONST will always be set to 1 if a key press is made, if the keyboard controller is powered on.

I'm very interested in how "old key presses" are handled.

If I start a process that wants to read keyboard input, and make a CONIN system call, and, if I have made a key press long before that, randomly, it seems like CONIN (by asserting CONST) should read the old key press as a new key press? This seems like the default case.

I can see ways to work around that, such as the processes clearing the status flag in keyboard controller as the first thing it does when it wants to get ready to accept keyboard input. Or, perhaps (but less likely), having some kind of signal to the keyboard controller that "activates" it.

How were "old characters" in buffer (and status register state) managed, generally?

Comment: This seems similar to the 86-DOS destructive vs nondestructive reads. To make sure a read is new, empty the buffers at one point. That is done by (nondestructively) polling for input and (destructively) reading that input, in a loop, until there is no more input available. Any reads after that will be sure to read new input.

Comment: @ecm Thanks! Good point. Good to know the standard approach to the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Keep in mind that if you call CONIN and there is no NEW character available, it will block until one is available.  That's the purpose of the CONST function, it allows an application to check for a key without blocking.

If there is a key, and you call CONIN, the key is returned and the buffer where it's been held is cleared along with the flag.  If you call CONIN again and there is no key, you will not get the old key, the call will block until there is one.

See this for BIOS example:
[BIOS example](http://cpuville.com/Code/CPM-on-a-new-computer.html)

Note the CONIN and CONST functions:

See how conin loops until the char is ready?  No timer, no interrupts, just polling the status bit until something happens.

```
conin:          ;returns console character in register a
in  a,(3)   ;get status
and 002h    ;check RxRDY bit
jp  z,conin ;loop until char ready
in  a,(2)   ;get char
AND 7fh ;strip parity bit
ret
```

Note how this just checks the status and never loops:

```
const:          ;console status, return 0ffh if character ready, 00h if not
in  a,(3)   ;get status
and 002h    ;check RxRDY bit
jp  z,no_char
ld  a,0ffh  ;char ready
ret
no_char:    ld  a,00h   ;no char
ret
```

Just to be clear, when a BIOS call like CONIN **blocks** it will **NOT** return until there is a character available.  If you call CONIN in a loop and there are no characters it will block or hang or wait until there is one.  It may wait there forever if nobody ever presses a key.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that repeatedly calling CONIN will return a new key every time. I wonder about how an "old character" that is left in the buffer (and flagged as "new" by the status flag) is treated by a process that initiates some kind of read loop for the first time.

Comment: The handling of the status flag and the buffer is the responsibility of the BIOS code.  Again it should NEVER return the old character but if called block until a new one is available.  Do you understand what I mean by "BLOCK" here?

Comment: If CONIN clears the status flag when it is called, and then waits for the status flag to be set, that could explain it. I don't know exactly what you mean with BLOCK here. Is BLOCK a CP/M term I can read up on? Or is it in a more general term in this context.

Comment: (Perhaps you mean "block" as in "pause the process and wait until the BIOS receives a new character" (like synchronous I/O often does). I was assuming the polling was done in the process repeatedly calling CONIN but if it is done by the BIOS then that works too. )

Comment: Remember that CP/M is a single-user, single-threaded OS.  There was no pre-emptive multitasking like we're used to these days with modern operating system.  So it was common for applications to block.  As I noted in the answer, if you call CONIN without a character available it will wait there without returning to the caller until a character is available, potentially forever.  That's why it was always important to call CONST before calling CONIN.

Comment: OK so you meant "block" in the same way as its usually meant in synchronous I/O. I'm interested in how CONIN avoids reading the status flag from some "old keypress". And it can be avoided if CONIN always clears the status flag when it is called, and then waits and polls it. Do you know if that is how it worked?

Comment: @BipedalJoe you are asking for things that are simply none of CP/M's business and thus not defined. CONIN reads the next character and blocks until one is read, while CONST checks if one is ready. Everything ast that is version and moreso machine and setup dependent.

Comment: As far as I can see it is not machine dependent. CONIN must clear the status flag CONST is supposed to check, when CONIN is first called, to avoid reading status flag from older key press. More or less. Or something equivalent, like the status flag being a toggle (switching each time key press changes, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, etc. ) Or else it seems like it could end up reading "old keypresses" and that is what I wondered about.

Comment: @BipedalJoe So, what if there is no flag? Wht if CONST just looks into the receive buffer if there is a char? Or looks at some hardware flag that gets cleared when a character is read. Point is that the internal workings of CONIN and CONST are part of the BIOS and the BIOS is machine specific. The only thing guaranteed is what they deliver.

Comment: I can only say what I think from my perspective. If the keyboard controller will operate somewhat independently. It will receive a char when a key is pressed. The process then wants to read with CONIN. If it does not clear or ignore whatever is there from before, it might read "old keypress" as if it was new. This is not a problem if it somehow clears the register it checks (which does not matter) when it is called, and then waits for new input. Otherwise it uses "typeahead" approach. I think it is possible to see what I wondered about.

Comment: I believe you're overthinking this in the context of today's systems.  CP/M was very low-level and the machine interface was quite simple.  There was no concept of a device driver or the like.  See my updated answer for more on how the BIOS worked.

Comment: I don't think I am. But I replied to Raffzahns long form answer and I agree that type ahead is good many times, and from what I gather from his answer, programs can manually clear whatever CONST checks before they start to poll for a new character, if they by any chance wanted to do so. I appreciate both of your answers, and it seems like I was pretty much on the right track with my assumptions.

Comment: I can say that I am thinking of in in the context of that I want to simulate a simple operative system in VHDL on a computer I built in VHDL. So, if I am overthinking things in the context of today's systems, it is good for me to stop doing so. Thank you both for helping me with the question.

Comment: CP/M itself did not support any sort of "typeahead".  In many cases the BIOS queued characters on input to implement a typeahead scheme but that was totally within the user's or the system developer's BIOS and not a part of CP/M.  I myself wrote a number of BIOSs for various machines and recall doing an interrupt-driven input queue.  But CP/M was never aware of it.

Comment: Well, if it does not do "type ahead" if there was already a character in the buffer (and we assume a one character buffer only, a hardware buffer), then it must be clearing the "new character" status of the buffer somehow before it starts to read. As far as I can see. Otherwise, it seems like "type ahead" by definition. It also seems like Raffzahn said that "type ahead" was the default. So, idk. But I appreciate both your answers still.

Comment: @BipedalJoe There is no before, bo old or new, there is no timekeeping of characters or alike. Either there is one (or more) characters waiting or not. BIOS always only peeks at the top most character. From your last comment I get the impression you're trying to design some FPGA computer made for CP/M to run atop. A computer more like a PC with keyboard as a special device. Right? I'll added a paragraph touching that to my answer.

Comment: I haven't rejected what you wrote in your answer. You also wrote it was type ahead. And jwh20 here wrote it was not. I appreciate both your answers!

Comment: @BipedalJoe I have a hard time to see the sense in you asking for some clearing. Why on earth should there be one? Think of it like a UART receive latch. It always contains the last character received. there is no clearing or whatsoever. Also, as soon as there is a single character latch, it also inherently operates as a 1 character type ahead - simply by existing. (P.S.: it helps to add whom you're replying to).

Comment: ecm mentioned in a comment that the standard approach to clearing buffer was destructive reads. if wanting to avoid type ahead is a silly idea then why would there be standard approaches to it. maybe it is, I'm no expert, but to me it seems like there would be many cases when type ahead (from "old input") wasn't desirable. I think people can tell who I replied to, I'm not disagreeing with you, and if there are no cases where anyone would ever want to avoid type ahead then fine by me.

Comment: Programs that didn't want to handle "old" characters (like terminal programs, for example), simply had a `while (conStatus) conIn ();` loop in front to clear any input buffers.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm very interested in how "old key presses" are handled.

Not at all. They are out of scope for CP/M.

The CONST and CONIN are direct mapped to respective [BIOS functions](https://www.seasip.info/Cpm/bios.html) of the same name (number 1/2 at offset 3 and 6).

Since the BIOS is machine specific, each and every handling of a keyboard buffer is as well depending on machine and manufacturer. After all, there are many ways that could be used, so CP/M as machine independent OS does not care.

> If I start a process

There are no distinct processes on CP/M. Only the OS and whatever is loaded. All without any form of encapsulation or further Handling.

> that wants to read keyboard input, and make a CONIN system call, and, if I have made a key press long before that, randomly, it seems like CONIN (by asserting CONST) should read the old key press as a new key press? This seems like the default case.

Exactly.

Except, there is no 'old' or 'new' key press, just a character coming in from the console device. A character that may be buffered in BIOS, some interface, or out in the terminals send buffer.

> I can see ways to work around that, such as the processes clearing the status flag in keyboard controller as the first thing it does when it wants to get ready to accept keyboard input.

There is no such function. Not just because it's out of scope, but also as there is not necessarily a keyboard controller at all, or one that features a resetable status. Of for that matter a dedicated keyboard device.

CP/M is build upon the idea of a console device, which more often than not is a real, external terminal, not some build in keyboard and screen hardware. There are zillions of ways such configuration can buffer or not. BIOS can do, Interface can do, modem can do, other side modem can do, terminal send buffer can do terminal keyboard buffer can do - and maybe more I'm not thinking of right now can do.

Important to programmers: none of that matters to CP/M. It offers to check if there is (at least) one char waiting to be processed (CONST) and to read wait for a character to come (CONIN).

At that point it's also important to know that input *may* come from some file as well. In that case, all future input is ready right *before* the program starts :))

> Or, perhaps (but less likely), having some kind of signal to the keyboard controller that "activates" it.

Not sure what that is supposed to mean.

> How were "old characters" in buffer (and status register state) managed, generally?

As said, not at all. Neither by BIOS, BDOS, CCP, nor application.

---

#### Howto Clear Waiting Input

Now it seems that your intend is to clear the buffer of any previous/waiting character at start your program. That's rather easy done by reading as long as there is a character waiting:

```
   while (CONST != 0) do CONIN.
```

#### Or Better Not

I would strongly suggest against doing so as it creates an unexpected behaviour. Users do rather quickly learn how a system behaves. Number of keypress that can be made while some activity is running - like loading data or starting a program - is one of them.

Sounds strange? Well, it's the way it was back then. Those weren't multi GHz systems with limitless memory and solid state drives transferring data a complete floppy a millisecond. Starting a program took several seconds plus several more for data files. All while the user was eager to continue work. Depending on setup and buffering capability he would already start typing before program load was finished.

This was not only common during program start, but as well while and other operation took it's time. Type ahead was an incredible useful feature for everyday life.

Clearing the buffer at some arbitrary point in the midst of that will stop that workflow and mangle the users mental image of what will happen.

Beside killing manual workflow, 'clearing' console input may destroy redirection. CP/M can redirect console input from other devices or from a file - like to automate a workflow. Since it's not defined if that input is already readable at program start or not, having such a 'clear' loop would possible render your program unusable with redirected input.

Bottom line: **DON'T**

---

#### And Now For Something Completely Different

From from [one of your comments](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26292/conin-console-in-in-cp-m-and-old-characters-in-character-latch/26296?noredirect=1#comment90299_26295) I get the impression you're trying to design some FPGA computer made for CP/M to run atop. A computer more like a PC with keyboard as a special device. In that case, I'd say build that keyboard interface a bit like the interface of a UART, using two ports:

- Port ONE delivers the a character when a character is available.

  If none is available it blocks (inserts wait states or what's appropriate)
- Port TWO delivers the character available in port one, unless Port one has been read (and not refilled). In that case it delivers ZERO.

The Hardware version of the BIOS calls is now simply done reading either port:

- CONIN is reading port ONE.
- CONST is reading port TWO.

That's it.

To realise this means creating two components:

- an internal flag holding the value of character present
- a latch to hold a character (width depending on the character definition)

operating like this:

- handling of a a received character depends on that flag

  - if cleared, the character gets put into the latch, the flag gets set
  - if set the character gets ignored (For buffering see below)
- the latch can be read via port ONE or TWO
- reading via port ONE depends on the flag:

  - if cleared, execution gets stopped until a character is received, that is the flag gets set (continue with set step)
  - if set, the character gets returned, the flag gets cleared.
- reading via port TWO depends as well on the flag:

  - if set, the character is returned
  - if cleared 'all bits zero' is returned.

Shouldn't be more than a hand full of lines in VHDL. Adding buffering becomes a modular addition. Now the 'character received' event does not trigger the latch handling, but gets bound to a FIFO, whose 'not empty' output gets routed to the latch's 'character received'

Also, note, any'clearing' attempt done in hardware will be so fast, that it contradicts any purpose.

Comment: Surely the normal way to start a new program is by running it from the prompt, meaning that the ENTER key will be the last thing read (and status-cleared) before the program runs. The first keystroke after that belongs to the program whether it's ready for it immediately or takes ten minutes before it tries to get it. In which case it would have been buffered for the program. So I've gotta go with Raffzahn here, the concept of old keystrokes doesn't come into play because all keystrokes after the program starts, belong to the program.

Comment: Thanks for answer. What I can gather from answer is that I was right that type ahead is the default case. I agree it is useful in many cases. And I assume that when it isn't desired then the program running (the process running in the transient program area) would have to clear/reset whatever is used to signal "new character", before reading. And I assume from answer that CONIN does not do that automatically, instead it has to be done manually. It all sounds good to me. Thanks for helping me get a better understanding!

Comment: @BipedalJoe Sorry, but I do not understand what you mean by _"And I assume from answer that CONIN does not do that automatically, instead it has to be done manually."_ What is it you want to have done? CONIN looks for a character and waits if none is there, after that it returns with that character. There is no flag to be handeled o otherwise. Likewise CONST checks if there is already a character waiting. Not less but as well not more. So if CONIN has read the last character present, CONST will return zero. Otherwise it returns non-zero.

Comment: OK. The char register set to 0 is the same as no new character then, I assume. I was assuming it would either use that approach, or have a separate status register. What I wondered about was if type ahead is default, or not. I think there are cases where type ahead isn't desirable. And I understand it can be manually turned off by clearing whatever is used to check if a new char is available. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo good point about the prompt ENTER being the last read (and status-cleared) before program runs. And thank you both again for helping me out with question.

Comment: @BipedalJoe So far above describes a solution based on latch and a flag internally, visible externally as two ports. This is important as it brings not only checking for character, but also a non destructive read which is mandatory in CP/M 3 (IIRC). A latch will always introduce a single character type ahead. without typing would be almost impossible considering the latencies of all components. If a program needs the exeptional case of making sure everything is cleared (can't really think of one), it needs to empty the latch until there is really no further content waiting.

Comment: Yes I understood that. And it verifies the assumption I had that type ahead was default. Whether or not programs would want to avoid it, I can't say for sure, but intuitively, if I play a game and it opens a query text field, I wouldn't want some random key press from before to pop up first. But I see how a program can avoid it if they want. The flag internally that is a port, sounds a bit like the status flag I was assuming might be there. Thanks for your answer, it helped me understand things better!

Comment: @BipedalJoe Well, I answered the question first from a software PoV. VHDL was only added in hindsight. I do some VHDL bungling at times, so the ports here are actively designed as character wide, not a latch and a bit. by doing so it offers read ahead (non destructive read) as well, which is extreme handy at times - for example for system components checking for certain input to hook special functions. Also, we're talking C/M, there are not many games. But even if, wouldn't a game opening an input box only do so as reaction to a user command, like 'save', which means input is already synced?

Comment: OK you meant for VHDL, I get it. Yes I built a UART and was going to use it for the keyboard. Will not be building CP/M but just a very simple OS that will probably be similar to the earliest operative systems... Maybe avoiding type ahead is not important, and any new text input request is a response to some other text input request, and maybe I was thinking about it in the context of having, for example, a mouse that I can click in this text field with. Still interested in how it is managed in that context but it's outside the scope of CP/M and also of the simulation I'm working on.

Comment: @BipedalJoe Well, mouse got the same issue and like with keyboard it can't be resolved by default. Infact it's even worse. I gues you also have already experienced to klick in expectance of a box or a new window but still hitting the one 'below' ? It's the way it was and still is. Primitive computers did not have keyboards at all. interactive text input as common feature only came up in the 60s. Bottom line, don't think about high level functions, get the basics right. Peeking for a character, seeing that without emptying, reading with emptying.  Thats what makes al things go.